# Google Map Fragment inside another Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer that replaces a framelayout with a supportmapfragment.  I am able to load the fragment fine the first time, but pressing that drawer item again gives the dreaded "duplicate binary" error.

I read from [Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment with Google Map Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775535/binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-fragment-with-google-map-fragment) that the error is due to the fact that the map fragment cannot be removed from the navdrawer's fragment if the map fragment exists in the xml.  He suggested a programmatic approach so I tried this:

NavDrawerFirstFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "In NavDrawerFirstFragment onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


public NavDrawerFirstFragment() {
    // fragment needs a no arg ctor
}


public static NavDrawerFirstFragment newInstance(Location currentLoc) {
    NavDrawerFirstFragment firstFragment = new NavDrawerFirstFragment();
    // how to set arguments for this fragment when this method is static
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("current_loc", currentLoc);
    firstFragment.setArguments(args);

    return firstFragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "NavDrawerFirstFragment onCreateView()");
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_drawer_first, container, false);

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment);
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

    }
    /*if(mMap == null) {
        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }*/

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "NavDrawerFirstFragment onStart()");
    super.onStart();

    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    // check for google play services here

    MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
    Location initialLoc = getArguments().getParcelable("current_loc");
    LatLng latlong = new LatLng(initialLoc.getLatitude(), initialLoc.getLongitude());

    Marker startingMarker = mMap.addMarker(mo.position(latlong).position(latlong).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
    startingMarker.setDraggable(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 12));
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "NavDrawerFirstFragment onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "NavDrawerFirstFragment onDetach()");
    super.onDetach();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "NavDrawerFirstFragment onResume()");
    super.onResume();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    if (mMapFragment != null)
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "NavDrawerFirstFragment onPause()");
    super.onPause();

    if (mMapFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

fragment_nav_drawer_first.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hnt_et_location"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is actually the solution proposed in another SO post: [Error opening SupportMapFragment for second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565460/error-opening-supportmapfragment-for-second-time)

When I debug it I notice that however long I wait before stepping into onStart(), my GoogleMap mMap is still null.  This is driving me bonkers and I would really appreciate the proper solution to consistently accessing a navdrawer fragment that isn't just a map but a searchbar and a map like I have.

Comment: Try to remove your Google map in `onPause()` method and add again in `onResume()` method.

Comment: use [MapView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html) instead of `MapFragment`.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because map already exits and you try to add it again with the same id ..
So you need to remove the map framegnt in `onPause` and have to again add it in `onResume`   :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    if (mMapFragment != null)
        mMap= mMapFragment.getMap();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mMapFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

## Update :

Move your `onStart` code to `onActivityCreated` as shown here :

```
mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {



    @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                initMap();

            }
        };


    public void initMap()
    {
              if (mMap== null) {
                    mMap= mMapFragment.getMap();
            }
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        // check for google play services here

        MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
        Location initialLoc = getArguments().getParcelable("current_loc");
        LatLng latlong = new LatLng(initialLoc.getLatitude(), initialLoc.getLongitude());

        Marker startingMarker = mMap.addMarker(mo.position(latlong).position(latlong).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        startingMarker.setDraggable(true);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 12));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I added all that(replacing mGoogleMap with my mMap of course) and mMap in onStart is still null, resulting in a null pointer exception.  I have posted the revised complete code in the OP.  Thanks

Comment: havnt you override `onActivityCreated` ??? remove this line `mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();`... @HukeLau_DABA

Comment: yes, I did, please see updated code in OP.  according to logcat logs, onCreate, onCreateView, onActivityCreated, then onStart where it crashes because mMap(your mGoogleMap) is null.

Comment: check update code..move ur code of onStart to onActivityCreated @HukeLau_DABA

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, thanks it was very useful for me too. Why is better init the map in onActivityCreate rather than onStart?